# Magento: Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in app\Mage.php on line 432

Tags: magento, fatal-error, mage

I want to call a PHP file using ajax where in that PHP i will place order by the ajax call. But it throws error while i am using app/Mage.php from that file

```
require_once '../../../../../../../../../../app/Mage.php';    
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
```

then it says

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a
>   non-object in app\Mage.php on line 432

Can anyone please help me???

Comment: I have solved it by using 


$customer  = new Mage_Customer_Model_Customer();


instead of using 


$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your proposed solution is not optimal. You have not initialized Magento so module XML is not loaded yet and the factory pattern does not work.

Simply use either:

```
Mage::init(); // 1.5+
```

or

```
Mage::app(); // (pretty much anything) below 1.5
```

before using getModel.

Comment: its shows me this error "Mage registry key "controller" already exists"

Comment: Thanks Daniel Sloof. I struggled a lot with this error. +11111111

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that helped.

Comment: 8 years later you're still helping people with this answer... +1

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize the Magento Framework first:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::init($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, array());
```

Comment: It seems like `Mage::init($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` would be more appropriate, but +1! (But note, I'm using Mage EE 1.12. Might be different for different versions :) Thanks, solved my error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize magento. the safest way to initialize it is by using initializer before your actual call to the model

Mage::init();

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message. The solution was different. I forgot to give the permission on the magento folder to the Apache.

```
chown -R apache:apache magento
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally had solved it by using

```
$customer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Customer();
```

instead of using

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
```