# Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php on line 463

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error

I install magento 1.9.0.0 and copy to my xampp htdocts when I run localhost/magento this error shows,i've done the solutions but it didn't work.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in    
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php on line 463
```

Here is the code script:

```
public static function getModel($modelClass = '', $arguments = array())
  {
    return self::getConfig()->getModelInstance($modelClass, $arguments);
  }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is related with some write permissions.
Set write permissions to the following folders `app/etc, var and media`.

```
cd /xampp-folde/htdocs/magento
chmod -R 777 app/etc
chmod -R 777 var
chmod -R 777 media
```

Comment: I think the magento team suppose to throw a reasonable exception when a directory is not writable instead of the referenced error.

Comment: There are many exceptions that the magento team could have handled better

Answer (score 12):

**In case you are getting this error while trying to access Magento outside in a script**

The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145373/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getmodelinstance-on-a-non-obje) should be considered first before playing with permissions.

`Mage::init(); // 1.5+`

`Mage::app(); // (pretty much anything) below 1.5`

Comment: Thankew imran bhai :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are running a custom script you might have forgotten to set the current store.

**Examples:**

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('my_store_id');
```

If you don't set a store then calls to `Mage::getModel` will result in the mentioned error.

Comment: This has helped me, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What is really causing your problem is that your Magento installation directory and files do not have correct permissions. XAMPP runs Apache as a user called `daemon` by default. If you don't want that, you can change it in `httpd.conf`. This solves the problem without doing anything else.

But you can just change the owner of the files, too. You should never grant everybody access to your files by just telling `chmod 777`. 777'ing your files is a major security issue if you ever move those files to a production environment.

Instead doing `chmod 777`, change the owner of the directory using `chown`. Go to your Magento directory (in your case `cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/`) and use this command to recursively change the owner of all files and directories to `daemon`:

`sudo chmod -R daemon .`

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize the Magento Framework first:

```
/* Store or website code */ 
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */ 
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::init($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, array());
```